# If given table of x and slope of each x, why would it be incorrect to say that the function is increasing?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let's say that we are given the information below

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x & -2 & 0 & 3 & 5 & 6 \\\hline
f'(x) & 3 & 1 & 4 & 7 & 5 \\\hline
\end{array}$$

We can see that all of the slopes are positive. So I come to the conclusion that the function increases from $(-2,6)$. However, my textbook states that it is incorrect. Why is this?

Comment: What about the intermediate values of $x$?

Comment: The counterexample is that in $x=1$, for example, the function could be decreasing, and the table doesn't indicate that.

Comment: @JohnRawls Yeah. So what if at $x=-1$, $f(-1)=-10$? Then $f$ would be decreasing thus your statement is false; you can't assume something you don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, $f'(x)$ represents the slope, which can decrease at the intermediate points. It need not be monotonous, it may fluctuate.